# How to initialize a list, where the types of elements in the list are unknown

Tags: r

For example say I want to initialize a list of vectors and matrices, but the vectors and matrices are of random dimension. For example, suppose the list I want to initialize is "y", and I want to do something like this

```
for(i in 1:10){
 len = round(100*runif(1))
 if(runif(1)<.5){
  y[i] = runif(len);
 } else { 
  y[i] = matrix(0,len,len);
}
```

I have read the documentation on lists but still can't figure this out. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284676/initialize-a-list-of-matrices-in-r) talks about initializing lists as does a few others, but not where the dimension of the elements of the list are unknown.

Here is a second example

```
for(i in 1:10){

 if(runif(1)<.5){
  len = round(100*runif(1))
  y[i] = runif(len);
  q[i] = matrix( rexp(len*len,1), len, len);
 } else { 
  len = round(90*runif(1))
  y[i] = matrix(0,len,len);
  q[i] = matrix( rexp(len*len,1), len, len);
}
```

Comment: Don't think you need to initialize anything.  Try using [[]] when defining your elements of y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid using for if you don't have any relation between iterations.

Use `replicate` here, it will create the right structure for you:

```
set.seed(123)
replicate(3,{                      ## replacee 3 by 10
  len = round(4*runif(1))          ## replace 4 by 100
  if(runif(1)<.5)   runif(len)
  else   matrix(0,len,len)
})

[[1]]
     [,1]
[1,]    0

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0

[[3]]
[1] 0.5281055 0.8924190 0.5514350 0.4566147
```

Comment: well my actual example has about 50 lines or so of code inside the loop with multiple user defined function calls and multiple lists needing to be created, with say list elements y[i] and q[i] and z[i] being related to each other. I just posted the above example because it gets at the gist of the initialization problem I was having. I'll have to think if replicate will work for that.

Comment: `replicate` works if iteration **i** don't depend of iteration **j** , Typically `replicate(N,generator)` where *generator* is an R expression with 1 , 50 or 100 statement.

Comment: oh OK I think I understand replicate now. I think I read the help file wrong. Thanks, so replicate should definitely work on example 2 above if I understand replicate correctly now.