# R: initialize m by n matrices in an empty list

Tags: r, list, matrix

I want to initialize an empty list that stores 10 2x5 matrices. I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284676/initialize-a-list-of-matrices-in-r) post here, and it seems like `replication(10, diag(2), simplify = F)` only returns a list of 10 empty 2x2 matrices. What if my matrix is not nxn? How can I account for that?

Comment: `rep(list(matrix(NA, 2, 5)), 10)`...and `diag(2)` is not empty, it's an identity matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a 3D array by specifying the dimensions

```
array(NA, c(2, 5, 10))
```

Or if we need a `list` of `matrices`

```
lapply(1:10, matrix, data= NA, nrow=2, ncol=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

`diag(2)` gives this,

```
       [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    0
 [2,]    0    1
```

Try,

```
replicate(10, matrix("", 2, 5), simplify = F)
```

which would generate 10 empty matrix with the required dimensions.